# Move an image with the arrow keys using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to move an image around the screen with JavaScript. The code I have below will put the image on the screen but will not let me move it around.

Question: Want to be able to move the image around the screen with the arrow keys?

I am certain there has to be a game loop that somehow is running all the time when the page is active. How this is done I am not certain either but I think that it might be int he  load function.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Move Object</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       <script type="text/javascript">

            function leftArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function rightArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

            }

            function upArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function downArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
            }

            function moveSelection() {
                evt = evt || window.event; 
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                    leftArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 39:
                    rightArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 38:
                    upArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 40:
                    downArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    }
                };

        function gameLoop()
        {
          // change position based on speed
          moveSelection();
          setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);
        }

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="gameLoop()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="" bgcolor='yellow'>
   Test
  <img id="image1" src="C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\mp.jpg" style="position:absolute;"
                                                              height="15" width="15">
  </body>
   end html
</html>
```

Comment: Not really. You need to set some "triggers" so, when they happen, the action is executed. I can only do it in jquery (javascript's framework), but still might give you some idea, want me to show it anyway?

Comment: You have duplicate opening script tags (and you don't need to specify the type in HTML5).

Comment: I would imagine the newest version of HTML. HTML 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an event listener for "keydown" which fires repeatedly, as long as the key is held down. I believe this would be the preferred approach.
Also, the initial values for 'top' and 'left' are nothing, so you need to assign initial values.

I created a fixed copy of your code here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kjEMr49wI0YFMQsf0iuC?p=preview

Comment: I have the image on my g:\ drive and want to use that instead but for some reason   <img id="msp.bnp" src="G:" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="15" width="15"> does not want to move the image around. nothing seems to happen other than I have a picture that stays in the same spot.

Comment: Does the same happen with a picture from a different location?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to set an initial left, right, et cetera. And get the event from keyup to get the key pressed and use the key for executing the right function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Move Object</title>



       <script type="text/javascript">

            function leftArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function rightArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
            }

            function upArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function downArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
            }

            function moveSelection(event) {                    
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                        leftArrowPressed();
                    break;

                    case 39:
                        rightArrowPressed();
                    break;

                    case 38:
                        upArrowPressed();
                    break;

                    case 40:
                        downArrowPressed();
                    break;
                }
            };

        function gameLoop()
        {
            // change position based on speed
            moveSelection();
            setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);
        }

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="gameLoop();" onkeydown="" onkeyup="moveSelection(event)" bgcolor='yellow'>
   Test
  <img id="image1" src="pug.jpeg" style="position: absolute; left: 15; right: 15; top: 15; bottom: auto; " height="15" width="15">
  </body>
   end html
</html>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to create a centipede game and have the object in the general direction until another key is pressed and also if the space bar is the fire key how would that affect the game loop?

Answer (score 0):

## Formatted HTML:

The formatted code formatted to fit your document.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Move Object</title>
    <script>
      function leftArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
      }

      function rightArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

      }

      function upArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
      }

      function downArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
      }

      function moveSelection(evt) {
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
          case 37:
            leftArrowPressed();
            break;
          case 39:
            rightArrowPressed();
            break;
          case 38:
            upArrowPressed();
            break;
          case 40:
            downArrowPressed();
            break;
        }
      };

      function docReady() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="" bgcolor='yellow'>
    <img id="image1" src="https://netphp.geonevestudios.repl.co/images/favicon/web-icon.ico" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="15" width="15">
  </body>

</html>
```