# JavaScript "animation" not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, css, dom, animation

I've been trying to move a red box 20px on mouseover. But instead of adding 20px to the current position it just goes to position "20px".

I got the idea for this here: [Move an image with the arrow keys using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790295/move-an-image-with-the-arrow-keys-using-javascript)

But it's not working for me :/

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#element {
position: absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
height: 140px;
width: 60px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="element"></div>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        boxElement = document.getElementById('element');
        if (boxElement) {
            boxElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                boxElement.style.left += 20 + 'px';
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

`boxElement.style.left` returns a **string** which looks like `"123px"`.

The first time you execute

```
boxElement.style.left += 20 + 'px';
```

it will be fine, since `boxElement.style.left` will be an empty string. But the second time, you are trying to set `style.left` to `20px20px` (string concatenation!), so the browser simply ignores the new value, and keep the old one, `20px`.

You have to parse the position out of the value first, using [**`parseInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and then add to it:

```
var left = boxElement.style.left;
boxElement.style.left = (parseInt(left, 10) + 20) + 'px';
```

The other problem is that `boxElement.style.left` won't return the initial value which was inherited from the CSS class. For that you can use [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) and set it once before you bind the event handler:

```
var boxElement.style.left = 
    window.getComputedStyle(boxElement,null).getPropertyValue("left");
```

---

If you read the code of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790295/move-an-image-with-the-arrow-keys-using-javascript) properly, you can see that that's exactly what was done there:

```
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
```

Comment: this isn't quite right - it will jump from 100px to 20px on the first mouseover. If you're going to do this you should either set the initial style to 100px on the element itself, or use the computed style instead of the style property

Comment: Yep, noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a string `"20px"` to an empty string, which is effectively setting the style property of the boxElement to `"left: 20px"`, overriding the stylesheet.

You could get the current computed style of the element each time and add to it, or you could keep a closure-scoped variable with the position, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var x=window.getComputedStyle(boxElement,null).getPropertyValue("left");

    boxElement = document.getElementById('element');
    if (boxElement) {
        boxElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            x+=20;
            boxElement.style.left = x + 'px';
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! But... how can I get the current style without "overriding" it when setting the x variable?

Something like var x = (parseInt(boxElement.style.left)); But it doesn't work... Ugh... I'm a noob.

Comment: I've borrowed Felix's getComputedStyle(...) code and edited it into my answer, if you would like to stay with the closure variable approach