# Javascript: Moving an Object with Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a simple Tetris game. So far I have a Tetris piece that rotates when the space bar is clicked.

The next step for me is to move the objects left and right using the arrow keys. From looking at other [Stack Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790295/move-an-image-with-the-arrow-keys-using-javascript) I found that this was possible by changing the margins.

```
        var angle = 0;
        var obj = document.getElementById('image')

        document.onkeydown = checkKey;

        function checkKey(e) {

            e = e || window.event;

            if (e.keyCode == '32') {
                rotate();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                moveLeft();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                moveRight();
            }

        }
        function rotate() {
            angle = angle + 90;
            console.log(angle)
            obj.className = "image" + angle;
            console.log(obj.className)
            if (angle == 360) {
                angle = 0;
            }
        }

        function moveLeft() {
            obj.style.left = parseInt(obj.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
        }

        function moveRight() {
            obj.style.left = parseInt(obj.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
        }
```

For some reason this isn't working for me.

I've also re-created my code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8ox0g15/#update) using a banana instead of a Tetris piece.

Comment: Try to use absolute or fixed positioning for #image, or left and right properties won't have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your Javascript, but with your styles. You need to absolutely position your image (banana in this case), and set an initial "left" value. The `position: absolute;` can be set either in the HTML or CSS, but the `left: 0;` must be set in the HTML style attribute. Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8ox0g15/1/) with the changes.