# How do you make images move with the arrow keys in HTML, Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not know how to make a figure move around on the screen in html. It is for a game that I am making. If anyone could come up with a way to do this please leave a comment. Your help would be much appreciated.
I also, have tried different ways like this - [Move an image with the arrow keys using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790295/move-an-image-with-the-arrow-keys-using-javascript) - but that didn't work for me.

```
<img id="player" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/smile/smile-09.jpg" 
     style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" height="15" width="15">
```

Thanks

Comment: If I can answer your question with: "With code, probably', you may want to reconsider the scope of this. What have you tried, where are are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below snippet. It should move the smiley face up, left, down, or right based off the WASD keys.

Based off your game, you may want to consider using different keys and a different amount to move the smiley face by whenever a directional key is pressed.

```js
var playerImage = document.getElementById('player');
var valueToMoveBy = 5;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 83:
      playerImage.style.top = parseInt(playerImage.style.top, 10) + valueToMoveBy + 'px';
      break;
    case 87:
      playerImage.style.top = parseInt(playerImage.style.top, 10) - valueToMoveBy + 'px';
      break;
    case 65:
      playerImage.style.left = parseInt(playerImage.style.left, 10) - valueToMoveBy + 'px';
      break;
    case 68:
      playerImage.style.left = parseInt(playerImage.style.left, 10) + valueToMoveBy + 'px';
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
});
```

```html
<img id="player" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/smile/smile-09.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" height="15" width="15">
```

One thing that may have thrown you off is how to apply calculations to pixels. You can't simply do 5px + 5px, so you must first convert 5px into 5 using `parseInt()` and then add the amount to move by. You can then convert the result to a `px` string and apply it to your corresponding style, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, for that. Except I can't get it to work. Am I supposed to modify the code? Am I supposed to use WASD or arrow keys?

Comment: @Dman1012 - Yes, you are supposed to modify the code for your needs. The 2nd paragraph in my answer indicates this.

Comment: I meant for it to work, so I can see what I should change.