# How to move an image in HTML with onkeypress

Tags: html

I am currently creating a program that allows the user to move an image to avoid falling blocks but I am stuck on getting the image to move. Ive been using onkeypress to move the picture with any button, eventually having it move with the arrow keys but so far the image doesn't move.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
    h1{
        font-size: 2.8em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #Screen{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px gray;
    }
    #car{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Drive your car with arrow keys</h1>
    <canvas id="Screen" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <div id="car" tabindex="0"></div>
    <div id="Screen"></div>
    <!-- <img id="car"  tabindex="0" src='race_car.png'> -->
    <script>
        var mycar = document.getElementById("car");
        mycar.onkeypress = moveCar();
        function moveCar(){
            console.log(mycar.offsetLeft);
            mycar.style.left = mycar.offsetLeft + 20 + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are going to want to use `keydown`. Try using `window.onkeydown = function(e) { alert(e.key) }` for a test. To learn more about window.onkeydown visit [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp). Also you are going to want to use CSS `transform` to move or adjust the `left` and `right` values.

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the event listener incorectly.

Use  `document.onkeypress = moveCar;`

```js
 var mycar = document.getElementById("car");
        document.onkeypress = moveCar;
        function moveCar(){
            console.log(mycar.offsetLeft);
            mycar.style.left = mycar.offsetLeft + 20 + "px";
        }
```

```css
  h1{
        font-size: 2.8em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #Screen{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px gray;
    }
    #car{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
        
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Drive your car with arrow keys</h1>
    <canvas id="Screen" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <div id="car" tabindex="0"></div>
    <div id="Screen"></div>
    <!-- <img id="car"  tabindex="0" src='race_car.png'> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to use `onkeypress`, which doesn't seem to work with the keyboard arrows. Per [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), this event only fires for a limited set of keys. There is a solution using `leftArrowPressed` (and the other arrow keys here: [Move an image with the arrow keys using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790295/move-an-image-with-the-arrow-keys-using-javascript)

In that example, you have full movement with the arrow keys. Per MDN, the [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is now deprecated, and `keydown` should be used instead (as in the example referenced above).